# Derby SQL using scalar subqueries and Order BY and FETCH NEXT to limit result to one

Tags: sql, derby

Here's a simplified SQL statement for what I'm trying:

```
SELECT * FROM cows WHERE lastMilkedDate = 
(SELECT milkDate from Lactaction order by 
milkDate desc FETCH NEXT ROW ONLY)
```

This will result in this error:

```
Error code -1, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: 
Encountered "FETCH" at line 1, column 148.
```

I've tried FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS too, same result.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps it's because it's in the subquery section. What happens if you  take the portion in the parentheses by itself and execute it as a standalone query?

Comment: @BryanPendleton the subsection works great. As parts both these queries are fine, as a whole it does not work.

Comment: I think I might be on to a workaround. It'll apply in this circumstance, but won't address any other FETCH issues in other queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I was able to do to solve my problem. I used a column function and a where clause to enforce one value. It opens up a new issue of making my view parametrized, but I'll have to address that…

```
SELECT * FROM cows WHERE lastMilkedDate = 
(SELECT MAX(milkDate) from Lactaction WHERE cowID=55)
```

Of course, this makes it a very specific query on 1 animal. I think I can rework other code to pass in the cowID.

Comment: Can't you simply remove the 'WHERE cowID=55' and get the behavior you want?

Comment: I'll have to check over my notes from last week. I had a bunch of problems with this query, it'll take a minute to put it all together. I do have the query I went with, I'll just have to make it SSCCE and repost it.